# Understanding a homework

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Question is: Write code to partition a linked list around a value x, such that all nodes less than x come before all nodes greater than or equal to x.

I was given this answer:

```
public Node partition(Node head, int x) {
    Node firstHead = null;
    Node secondHead = null;
    Node n = head;

    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }

    while (n != null) {
        Node next = n.next;

        if (n.data < x) {
            n.next = firstHead; *
            firstHead = n;
        }
        else {
            n.next = secondHead;
            secondHead = n;
        }

        n = next; **
    } 

    if (firstHead == null) {
        return secondHead;
    }
    else {
        n = firstHead;

        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }

        n.next = secondHead;

        return firstHead;
    }
}
```

For example, if the list is 3 7 9 1 4 8 2 3 and you are to partition at x=4 then inside the first while loop second element (7) would be set to null (where there is a star in the code) then n will be set 7 again (where there is two stars). I am not quite sure how this works? Is another node in the LinkedList created and the null is pushed back? Sorry for any trouble

Comment: Make sure to tag the language.

Comment: Also write an actual question in the title.. and "How do I understand this homework?" is not acceptable either. Make it a question that involves your code and your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have trouble with a few lines, so I'll try and explain

```
 n.next = firstHead; // This is the first step of an Insert, remove the next pointer.
                     // There may be (and is) a second level of looping where we
                     // find the new next value, but it might involve a second swap.
 firstHead = n;      // so make sure to store the current node.


 n = next;           // continue down the list of nodes to find the correct place for
                     // firstHead (if we have one).
```

If I'm wrong about what you're asking I'll remove this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "setting 7 to null", it's just setting `3`'s next pointer to null, meaning the node containing 3 does not have a next node.

To explain the code, note that it tries to create two new linked lists, one starting from `firsthead` and second starting from `secondhead`. The first one will chain the elements that have less value than `x` and the second equal or more value that `x`.

first both the linked lists are empty (the heads are null)

In the `while` loop, it iterates on the original list and for each element checks that if its data is less than `x` then adds it to the first list and if not, adds it to the second. It seems you are having trouble understanding this part. Note that this line `n.next = firsthead` means that append n to the head of the first list. Before this line the first list was starting from `firsthead`, now it starts from `n` and `n` points to `firsthead`. Then the `firsthead` pointer (which is supposed to show the "head" of the list), updates to refer to this new head.

See this sketch:

before:

```
firsthead
    \
     \           &
      _|                   (next)
        X (NULL)       [3]--------> [7]---------> [9]--------> ...
```

middle (after the * line):

```
firsthead
    \
     \           &                       &
      _|                   (next)
        X              [3]--------> X        [7]---------> [9]---------> ...
```

after:

```
firsthead
    \
     \                     &
      _|
       [3]---------> X          [7]--------> [9]--------> ...
```

You see? Now the first list is going to shape, it got it's first item.

After 4th running of the while loop which it gets to `1` it becomes:

```
firsthead
    \
     \
      _|
       [1]--------> [3]-------> X
```

Second list is like that too.

In the end it has two separate lists, and to get one list it iterates to first one's end, then concatenates it with the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;   
import java.util.*;
class ListNode
{
 int data;
 ListNode next;

  public ListNode(int data)
  {
    this.data=data;
  }

  public void setData(int data)
  {
    this.data=data;
  }

  public int getData()
  {
    return this.data;
  }
 public void setNext(ListNode next)
 {
   this.next= next;
 }

 public ListNode getNext()
  {
    return this.next;
  }
}

class LinkedList
 {
   ListNode head;
   int length =0;

   public LinkedList()
    {
      length=0;
    }
  public ListNode getHead()
   {
     return head; 
   }

  public int length()
 {
  return length;
 }

public void insertAtEnd(ListNode node)
 {
   String res="";
   if(head==null)
     head = node;
   else
      {
       ListNode p,q;
       for(p=head;(q=p.getNext())!=null;p=q);
              {p.setNext(node);}
      }

   length++;
  }
 public String toString()
 {
   String result="[";
   if(head==null)
      {
         return result+"]";
      }
  result= result+head.getData();
  ListNode temp = head.getNext();
  while(temp!=null)
 {
  result=result+","+temp.getData();
  temp=temp.getNext();
 }
 return result+"]";
 }

public void partition(int k)
{
 ListNode prev=null;
 ListNode pointer=head;
 ListNode innerPointer=head;
ListNode prevInnerPointer=null;
ListNode temp=null; 
int flag=0; 
 while(pointer!=null)
 {
  if(pointer.getData()<k && prev!=null)
     {
        temp=pointer;
        prev.setNext(pointer.getNext());
        pointer=prev.getNext();

      if(prevInnerPointer!=null)
          prevInnerPointer.setNext(temp);
           if(flag==0)
              {
               head=temp;
               flag=1;
               }     
      temp.setNext(innerPointer);
      prevInnerPointer=temp;
      innerPointer=temp.getNext();
    }
   else if(pointer.getData()<k)
          {
           head=pointer;
           flag=1;
           prevInnerPointer=innerPointer;
           innerPointer=innerPointer.getNext();
           prev=pointer;
           pointer=pointer.getNext();
          }        
   else
   {
   prev=pointer;
   pointer=pointer.getNext();
   }
 }
}
}
class START
{
 public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    LinkedList obj = new LinkedList();
    int i,num=0;
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter numbers ");       
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        num=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
        ListNode a = new ListNode(num);
        obj.insertAtEnd(a);
      }
    System.out.println("length:"+obj.length());
    String res=obj.toString();
    System.out.println(res);  
    int k = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
    obj.partition(k);
    System.out.println(obj.toString());
 }

}
```